# Posting JSON to API with URL on IOS

Tags: ios, json, post, alarm

I have designing an alarm and according to that alarm I need to post on api what the user set as alarm, later api will handle the procedure and notif me if the alarm time is come. So basically, I searched all day long and come with those:

Here what I came so far with tons of efforts! Please help me for further..

```
 NSMutableDictionary *alarmDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
    NSLog(@"token: %@", self.token);
    [alarmDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:42] forKey:@"Token"];
    NSLog(@"kur id: %lu", alarm.kurID);
    [alarmDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:alarm.kurID] forKey:@"CurrencyId"];
    NSLog(@"not val: %f", alarm.kurAlis);
    [alarmDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:alarm.kurAlis] forKey:@"NotificationValue"];
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)alarm.kurTur);
    [alarmDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:alarm.kurTur] forKey:@"Type"];

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:alarmDic
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    NSString *dataLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-dvzalt.azurewebsites.net/api/Notification/PostNotification"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:dataLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(conn) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
```

In the log windows,

```
requestReply: Connection Successful
```

However, nothing happening on the api, telling this as always.

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

Here is the confusion I have. It says connection succesful but on API, still the same. What should I do in this case? I might skip something but I can't figure out what I skip. I've done with the whole steps I suppose.

Note: API is working great, it is about my code most probably.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So I'm curious if you don't have a field name for the JSON data in your web handler?  Something like "jsonData"?  Right now you're stuffing the JSON data in your body, but there's no identifying field name for the handler to pull it out.

I'm thinking something like:

```
NSString jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jsonData=%@", jsonString];
```

Then encode requestString and use it in your body.

Comment: So I stuckted with one thing. Where exactly should I put that requestString? HTTPBody, did you mean with body ? It needs to take a data..